# Why is Gauss' Law for Electric Fields still applicable when $\vec{E}=kr^3\hat{r}$?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law

Problem 2.9 from Griffith's "Introduction to Electrodynamics"

Suppose the electric field in some region is found to be $\vec{E}=kr^5\hat{r}$, in
spherical coordinates ($k$ is some constant). Find the charge density $\rho(\vec{r})$ and the total charge enclosed by a spherical surface of radius $R$.

---

I obtained the charge density with $\nabla\cdot\vec{E}=\frac{1}{\epsilon_0}\rho(\vec{r})$ which gave the correct answer ($5\epsilon_okr^2$)

Similarly, the total charge can be calculated using $\oint_S\vec{E}\cdot\hat{n}dS=\frac{q_{enc}}{\epsilon_0} \to q_{enc}=4\pi\epsilon_0kR^5$

---

Why is it that the two formulae above (differential, integral, Gauss' Law) still hold even when $E$ no longer falls off as $\frac{1}{r^2}$?

Isn't Gauss' Law for electric fields $=\frac{q_{enc}}{\epsilon_0}$derived based on the assumption that the $r^2$ (one from $d\vec{S}_{spherical}$ and the other from $\vec{E}$) cancel, otherwise the flux would depend on the radius of the sphere and we would need to know the relation bewteen $k$ and $q_{enc}$?

Comment: $1/r^2$ is for a point charge. Now you have many many point charges inside the sphere. The charge distribution renders the field to the $r^5$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Isn't Gauss' Law for electric fields $=\frac{q_{enc}}{\epsilon_0}$derived based on the assumption that the $r^2$ (one from $d\vec{S}_{spherical}$ and the other from $\vec{E}$) cancel, otherwise the flux would depend on the radius of the sphere and we would need to know the relation between $k$ and $q_{enc}$?

It is easiest to see that $\Phi_E = \oint \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{a} = \frac{q_{enc}}{\epsilon_0}$ for spherical volumes surrounding point charges, and that's generally how it's justified to students.  But in fact, it holds for for *all* volumes and charge configurations (not just spherical volumes surrounding point charges).  And if you buy that, you can then show that $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{E} = \rho/\epsilon_0$;  in other words, the two statements are equivalent.  The way to show this (informally) is as follows:

Imagine a cuboid spanning the coordinates $[x, x+\Delta x]$, $[y, y+\Delta y]$, and $[z, z+\Delta z]$.  We will assume that $\Delta x$, $\Delta y$, and $\Delta z$ are "small" in some appropriate sense.  The net flux through the faces whose normals are in the $x$-direction is approximately
$$
\Phi_{E,x} \approx [E_x(x+\Delta x, y, z) - E_x(x,y,z)]\Delta y \Delta z = \frac{E_x(x+\Delta x, y, z) - E_x(x,y,z)}{\Delta x} \Delta x \Delta y \Delta z \approx \frac{\partial E_x}{\partial x} \Delta V
$$
where $\Delta V \equiv \Delta x \Delta y \Delta z$.  Note that the fluxes have opposite signs because the face at $x$ has normal $-\hat{\imath}$ while the face at $x +\Delta x$ has normal $+\hat{\imath}$. Similarly, the net fluxes through the pairs of faces facing in the $y$ and $z$ directions are
$$
\Phi_{E,y} \approx \frac{\partial E_y}{\partial y} \Delta V \qquad \Phi_{E,z} \approx \frac{\partial E_z}{\partial z} \Delta V 
$$
respectively.  Thus, the total flux through these surfaces is approximately
$$
\Phi_E = \left( \frac{\partial E_x}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial E_y}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial E_z}{\partial z} \right) \Delta V = (\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{E}) \Delta V.
$$
And if Gauss's Law holds for this volume, which holds a charge $\Delta q$, then we have
$$
(\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{E}) \Delta V \approx \Phi_E = \frac{\Delta q}{\epsilon_0}
\quad \Rightarrow \quad \vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{E} \approx \frac{1}{\epsilon_0} \frac{\Delta q}{\Delta V} \approx \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}.
$$
All of the "approximately equals signs" above become exact equalities in the limit that $\Delta x, \Delta y, \Delta z \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

As it is pointed out in the comment that $1/r^2$ is for a point charge. And a charge distribution can make of any kind of field like in this case that goes like $r^5$.

---

As an example, consider potential due to a change distribution $\rho(x',y',z')$. If you recall the [multipole expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_expansion) that looks like
$$\phi_A=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left[\frac{K_0}{r}+\frac{K_1}{r^2}+\frac{K_2}{r^3}+\cdots\right]$$
So you see, You get different powers of $r$ here.

---

But Even so, the field and the charge distribution is not physicals both tend to infinite as $r\rightarrow \infty$. That's the reason then asked for charge only inside the sphere. The physical field goes to zero as you go to infinite.